# Why can't I get the DIV child element from LI?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why does the code always return false?
Why can't I get the DIV child element from LI?

```js
let li = document.getElementById('ul').children
console.log(li)
for(i=0;i<li.length;i++)
  li.hasChildren ? console.log("true") : console.log("false")// only false
```

```html
<div id="conteinerTask2">
    <ul id="ul">
        <li class= "el">Element 1
            <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem eum quibusdam obcaecati sunt nulla, culpa nesciunt quas in officia sit. Illo aliquam beatae amet eos placeat neque, earum officiis ratione reiciendis exercitationem.</div></li>
        <li class= "el">Element 2
            <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ex commodi, laudantium corrupti nam quos.</div></li>
        <li class= "el">Element 3
            <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa obcaecati delectus nulla aperiam sint sit aliquam natus! Voluptatum, minima libero.</div></li>
        <li class= "el">Element 4
            <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in your `for` loop you're only accessing the *collection* of `li` elements, not each `li` individually because you don't access them by index.

Secondly, there is no `hasChildren` property. You can use `children.length > 0` instead.

Here's a working example with the above corrections made:

```js
let li = document.getElementById('ul').children

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].children.length > 0 ? console.log("true") : console.log("false") // only false
}
```

```html
<div id="conteinerTask2">
  <ul id="ul">
    <li class="el">Element 1
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem eum quibusdam obcaecati sunt nulla, culpa nesciunt quas in officia sit. Illo aliquam beatae amet eos placeat neque, earum officiis ratione reiciendis exercitationem.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="el">Element 2
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ex commodi, laudantium corrupti nam quos.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="el">Element 3
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa obcaecati delectus nulla aperiam sint sit aliquam natus! Voluptatum, minima libero.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="el">Element 4
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) returns an live [`HtmlCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You need to index it in your for-loop. Also these is no <strike>`hasChildren`</strike>. Use [`hasChildNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes)

```
 li[i].hasChildNodes() ? console.log("true") : console.log("false")
```

For sake of completeness

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById("ul");
for (const child of myElement.children) {
  const result = child.hasChildNodes ? "true" : "false";
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<div id="conteinerTask2">
  <ul id="ul">
    <li class="el">Element 1
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem eum quibusdam obcaecati sunt nulla, culpa nesciunt quas in officia sit. Illo aliquam beatae amet eos placeat neque, earum officiis ratione reiciendis exercitationem.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="el">Element 2
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ex commodi, laudantium corrupti nam quos.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="el">Element 3
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa obcaecati delectus nulla aperiam sint sit aliquam natus! Voluptatum, minima libero.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="el">Element 4
      <div class="el-txt">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, u have a syntax issue in ur JS code. Instead of `li.hasChildren`, try `li[i].hasChildNodes()`. Keep in mind that children returns a collection, so you need to access individual elements using array indexing.

```
let liElements = document.getElementById('ul').children;

for (let i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
    let li = liElements[i];
    
    // Check if the LI element has child nodes
    let hasChildren = li.hasChildNodes();
    
    console.log(`LI element ${i + 1}: ${hasChildren ? 'true' : 'false'}`);
}
```